# Finding elements from a list on Sage

Tags: python, sage

I have a file with the following content, that I import in Sage.

```
James,4626544,56565656
Julian,4646463,346346364
Perez,4626544,56565656
Paul,7658568,56565656
Ronaldo,4626544,8468568
Zlatan,4626544,56565656
```

Now from a Sage worksheet (.sagews), I want to recover the lines corresponding to names starting with letters from P to R (recover: Perez, Paul and Ronaldo).

I tried

```
for x in THEFILE
    print from x[0][0]='P' to x[0][0]='R'
```

and got an error. How I do this? (I already imported the file in the Sage worksheet to work with it).

Comment: You will need to give more details on this.  What sort of error?  How did you load/import `THEFILE`?  Please put all commands and output, otherwise it's pretty hard to debug.

Comment: Also, it looks like you also asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389809/trouble-with-arrays-on-sage so please close that one if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the file was read into Sage, `THEFILE`
might be a list of strings corresponding to lines in the file,
ie

```
['James,4626544,56565656',
 'Julian,4646463,346346364',
 'Perez,4626544,56565656',
 'Paul,7658568,56565656',
 'Ronaldo,4626544,8468568',
 'Zlatan,4626544,56565656']
```

or a list of lists of strings:

```
[['James', '4626544', '56565656'],
 ['Julian', '4646463', '346346364'],
 ['Perez', '4626544', '56565656'],
 ['Paul', '7658568', '56565656'],
 ['Ronaldo', '4626544', '8468568'],
 ['Zlatan', '4626544', '56565656']]
```

Use either x[0] or x[0][0] accordingly in the following.

To print:

```
for x in THEFILE:
    if 'P' <= x[0] <= 'R':
        print(x)
```

To get an extracted list:

```
P_to_R = [x for x in THEFILE if 'P' <= x[0] <= 'R']
```

The Python `csv` module, or the `pandas` package could help
with such data handling too:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/

To install `pandas` in your Sage, run the following in a terminal:

```
sage --pip install pandas
```